# Run & share a single Server instance for tests in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2017

My Visual Studio 2017 project contains a few unit test projects. All these Tests run against one single ASP.NET Core Server. I want to start the ASP.NET Core Server once before all tests and shut it down after all tests.

My main test project contains a class for starting the test Server:

```
public class TestServer : IDisposable
{
  public static string Url { get { return "http://localhost:44391/"; } }

  private static string GetApplicationPath()
  {
    return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "..", "..", "..", "..", "..", "..", "src", "MyProject"));
  }

  public IWebHost BuildHost()
  {
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseEnvironment("UnitTests")
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls(TestServer.Url)
        .UseContentRoot(GetApplicationPath())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
    return host;
  }


  private IWebHost _testserver;
  public TestServer()
  {
    _testserver = BuildHost();
    _testserver.Start();
  }

  #region IDisposable

  ~TestServer()
  {
    Dispose(false);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  bool _IsDisposed = false;

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposeManagedResources)
  {
    if (this._IsDisposed)
      return;
    if (disposeManagedResources)
    {
      _testserver.Dispose();
    }
    this._IsDisposed = true;
  }
  #endregion
}
```

To start the test server I added this helper class:

```
public static class TestServerStaticHelper
{
  static object LockServer = new object();
  static int ServerCount = 0;
  static TestServer _service;
  public static void Attach()
  {
    lock (LockServer)
    {
      ServerCount++;
      if (_service == null)
        _service = new TestServer();
    }
  }
  public static void Detach()
  {
    lock (LockServer)
    {
      ServerCount--;
      if (ServerCount <= 0 && _service != null)
      {
        _service.Dispose();
        _service = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I attach and detach the service from a TestClass containing functions for `[AssemblyInitialize()]` and `[AssemblyCleanup()]`

```
[TestClass]
public class TestServerFixture
{
  [AssemblyInitialize()]
  public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
  {
    TestServerStaticHelper.Attach();
  }

  [AssemblyCleanup()]
  public static void AssemblyCleanup()
  {
    TestServerStaticHelper.Detach();
  }
}
```

This works very well for my main test assembly. But if I add another assembly with tests, containing the TestServerFixture for Assembly-Init and Cleanup they won't share the service. Instead Visual Studio testing will try to start the service twice.

I guess every project / assembly containing tests is startet in a separate application domain?

How do I share a static server/service between several test assemblies?